# Как контролировать доступ к группе объектов

Tags: разработка-игр, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток.

**Ситуация следующая**: есть класс физического компонента - PhysicsComp. Данный класс хранит указатель на объект представляющий геометрическую фигуру. Все геометрические фигуры наследуются от базового класса Shape. Однако, помимо наследуемых свойств и методов, каждый конкретный класс фигуры имеет какие-то свои методы и свойства, которые отсутствуют у других фигур.

**В чем проблема:** Классу PhysicsComp необходимо отслеживать момент, когда изменяется положение, размер или ориентация фигуры и выполнять некоторые действия как перед непосредственным изменением так и после (т.е. как бы в начале и конце некоторого set метода).

**Как я пытался решить проблему:** Из доступных фигур у меня были - точка, отрезок, прямоугольник, эллипс. Я хотел воспользоваться паттерном "Заместитель", но не смог подобрать общего интерфейса для всех этих фигур.

Пожалуйста, подскажите - как можно решить мою проблему.

Comment: Не знаю как по шаблонам проектирования, но это очень похоже на шаблон pub/sub или observer наоборот. К примеру, фигуры Shape могут наследовать интерфейс IPropertyChanged, который выбрасывает событие-уведомление при изменении свойств. В свою очередь PhysicsComp случает эти события и делает свои дела.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex Krass. Примерно так я и поступил - добавил интерфейс владельца фигур. Но хотелось бы найти общий интерфейс для всех фигур перечисленных в моем вопросе. Что бы вы могли посоветовать на этот счет?

Comment: Я бы подсмотрел у других, какими паттернами они пользуются. Большие проекты как я понял используют паттерн ECS (entity component system). Пример с хабра: https://habr.com/ru/post/343778/ Можно попробовать покопать какой-нибудь OpenSource и посмотреть что-нибудь на https://gcup.ru/.

Comment: Кстати если покапаться по ссылкам, можно найти много интересного. С того же хабра ссылка на книгу Game Programming Patterns от разработчика из Electronic Arts: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо за хорошие советы, Alex Krass. Дело в том, что я как раз и использую ECS. Просто некоторые компоненты могут хранить ссылки на другие объекты. А что касается предложенной вами книги - очень хороший материал - я его не раз перечитывал. В любом случае - спасибо за помощь.